# .NET lambda XML OrderBy attribute if attribubute exists

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, lambda

I am trying to sort an xml attribute by sequence if the attribute exists. 
If it doesn't I want it to just continue as normal.

Currently I have :

```
 Dim children As IEnumerable(Of XmlNode) = dbElements.ChildNodes.Cast(Of XmlNode)().OrderBy(Function(r) r.Attributes("sequence").Value)
```

This works correctly if every XmlNode has the attribute. If it doesn't I get an object not set to instance error as expected. How can I modify this expression to check if the sequence exists first?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `Attributes("sequence") IsNot Nothing` first, get the attribute's `Value` if the condition met, or return default value otherwise :

```
Dim children As IEnumerable(Of XmlNode) = _
       dbElements.ChildNodes _
                 .Cast(Of XmlNode)() _
                 .OrderBy(
                   Function(x) If(x.Attributes("sequence") IsNot Nothing, x.Attributes("sequence").Value, "")
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to order if the attribute does not exist, but you can try something like this

.OrderBy(r => r.Attributes["sequence"] == null ? "" : r.Attributes["sequence"].Value)

Comment: Thanks, answer is in C# but still mirrors a correct answer.